# How to multiply a column based on a string in another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
for names in se1:
if se1['SE Assigned'] == 'Anthony':
    se1['Net Amount'] * .0666
else:
    pass
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Sample DataFrame:

```
   SE Assigned  Net_Amount Centers
0   0  Anthony      2060.0    ORD4
1   1  Anthony      1593.0    LAS1
```

Currently I am trying to run though all of my rows in my df and if the name is == Anthony in column I want to multiply the corresponding column by .0666 (se1['Net Amount']). Why am I getting this error? I added sample data below.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to apply a change to specific values:

Given:

```
   SE Assigned  Net_Amount Centers
0   0  Anthony      2060.0    ORD4
1   1  Anthony      1593.0    LAS1
2   2      Bob      1023.0    JFK3
```

Doing:

```
df.Net_Amount = df.Net_Amount.mask(df.Assigned.eq("Anthony"), df.Net_Amount.mul(0.0666))
```

Output:

```
   SE Assigned  Net_Amount Centers
0   0  Anthony    137.1960    ORD4
1   1  Anthony    106.0938    LAS1
2   2      Bob   1023.0000    JFK3
```